# How to utilise the date_parser parameter of pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting an issue with the `timestamp` column in my csv file.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2020-02-21 22:00:00'

for this line:

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
from datetime import datetime
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

"Import dataset"
df = pd.read_csv('fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv')


train, test = df[:-3], df[-3:]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train) <----------- This line
train = scaler.transform(train)
test = scaler.transform(test)

n_input = 3
n_features = 4

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train, train, length=n_input, batch_size=6)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizers='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=180)
```

How can I convert the `timestamp` column (preferably when reading the csv) to a float?

[image]

**Link to the dataset**: [https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=GBP&to_symbol=USD&interval=1min&apikey=OF7SE183CNQLT9DW&datatype=csv](http://Stock%20DataSet)

Comment: Are you trying to convert datetime column into float?

Comment: Yes the csv came with a timestamp column in the above mentioned format.

Comment: are you looking for unix time format?

Comment: Im using minmax scaler and lstm not sure what's best?

Comment: Are all timestamp strings in the column the same exact format?

Comment: yes they are, it's intraday stock data

Comment: WRT to Aiden's answer, which field of df do you need to pass to datetime.strptime().. obviously not the whole frame. What field of df has the time string in it?

Comment: timestamp column (1 of 5) has the date time format in it. Whenever I try to fit the scaler on training data I get the could not convert string (timestamp) to float

Comment: The csv is 1 minute forex intervals from Alpha advantage

Comment: @GGr can you please update the title and put a brief explanation that this is a pandas question on how to utilize the `date_parser` parameter of `pandas.read_csv()`.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the dataframe? Maybe a snapshot

Comment: Done, sorry I was writing this out on the mobile had to log in to the site to add extra info.

Comment: The link to the csv data isn't working. @GGr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performing Conversion On CSV Input Columns While Reading In The Data

Reading in CSV data applying conversion to the timestamp column to get float values:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv', 
...                  converters={'timestamp': 
...                                 lambda t: pd.Timestamp(t).timestamp()})
>>> df
       timestamp    open    high     low   close
0   1.582322e+09  1.2953  1.2964  1.2953  1.2964
1   1.582322e+09  1.2955  1.2957  1.2952  1.2957
2   1.582322e+09  1.2956  1.2958  1.2954  1.2957
3   1.582322e+09  1.2957  1.2958  1.2954  1.2957
4   1.582322e+09  1.2957  1.2958  1.2955  1.2956
..           ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
95  1.582317e+09  1.2966  1.2967  1.2964  1.2965
96  1.582317e+09  1.2967  1.2968  1.2965  1.2966
97  1.582317e+09  1.2965  1.2967  1.2964  1.2966
98  1.582317e+09  1.2964  1.2967  1.2962  1.2966
99  1.582316e+09  1.2963  1.2965  1.2961  1.2964

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

This can be applied to other columns too. The `converters` parameter takes a dictionary with the key being the column name and the value a function.

`date_parser` could be useful if the timestamp data spans more than one column or is in some strange format. The callback can receive the text from one or more columns for processing. The `parse_dates` parameter may need to be supplied with `date_parser` to indicate which columns to apply the callback to. `date_parser` is just a list of the column names or indices. An example of usage:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv', 
                 date_parser=lambda t: pd.Timestamp(t), 
                 parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

`pd.read_csv()` with no date/time parameters produces a timestamp column of type `object`. Simply specifying which column is the timestamp using `parse_dates` and no other additional parameters fixes that:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv', 
                     parse_dates=['timestamp'])
>>> df.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
open                float64
high                float64
low                 float64
close               float64
```

### Conversion of DataFrame Columns After Reading in CSV

As another user suggested, there's another way to convert the contents of a column using `pd.to_datetime()`.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv')
>>> df.dtypes
timestamp     object
open         float64
high         float64
low          float64
close        float64
dtype: object
>>> df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
>>> df.dtypes
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
open                float64
high                float64
low                 float64
close               float64
dtype: object
>>> 
>>> df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda t: t.timestamp())
>>> df
       timestamp    open    high     low   close
0   1.582322e+09  1.2953  1.2964  1.2953  1.2964
1   1.582322e+09  1.2955  1.2957  1.2952  1.2957
2   1.582322e+09  1.2956  1.2958  1.2954  1.2957
3   1.582322e+09  1.2957  1.2958  1.2954  1.2957
4   1.582322e+09  1.2957  1.2958  1.2955  1.2956
..           ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
95  1.582317e+09  1.2966  1.2967  1.2964  1.2965
96  1.582317e+09  1.2967  1.2968  1.2965  1.2966
97  1.582317e+09  1.2965  1.2967  1.2964  1.2966
98  1.582317e+09  1.2964  1.2967  1.2962  1.2966
99  1.582316e+09  1.2963  1.2965  1.2961  1.2964

[100 rows x 5 columns]
```

Or to do it all in one shot without `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/fx_intraday_1min_GBP_USD.csv')
>>>
>>> df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'] \
...                      .apply(lambda t: pd.Timestamp(t).timestamp())
>>>
```

Comment: @GGr - Okay. I've updated this. I think the answer might have been incorrect when you selected it as the **Answer**, but I've done some experimenting, and I've come up with what I think will work. See above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to convert a string into a Datetime object.

To do this, you would need to use `datetime.strptime` with a formatting string as the second argument. This string would need to match the format of the date within your csv file.

So you would need this code to convert your time string into a Datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('intraday.csv')
dftime = datetime.strptime(df, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

After this, you can do whatever you want to do with `dftime`. If you want it to be a float (or timestamp), you can use this code:

```
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(dftime)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I get the error strptime() argument 1 must be a str, not data frame

Comment: @GGr, don't pass the whole frame to the strptime() function - Aiden was only doing that for example. One user here posted an answer that looked promising, but deleted it =(

Comment: Yeah I never had a second chance to say wait the infer datetime came back fine, I was running my entire cell instead of running the section

Comment: @GGr so using `infer_datetime_format=True` solved the issue??

Comment: It didn't solve it, it's still a string not a float. I just didn't get the other error from the other question.

Comment: @GGr perhaps setting `datetime_parser` to a function that converts the string will do the trick like the poster who deleted their answer suggested.

Comment: If I use the previous questions answer I get a type error invalid type promotion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208304/discussion-between-todd-and-g-gr).

Answer (score -1):

you can use pandas method to convert whole column to datetime:

import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(column)

and then if you want this column as a index use:

pd.set_index(column)

Comment: Although this provides some clues, it's not enough info to go by.